# RxAndroidBle - Long write and listen to notification characteristic

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm very new when it comes to the android / BLE space. I'm attempting to write to a characteristic and listen on the notification using the RxAndroidBle library. I've looked at many implementations that just seem to be different enough that I can't get my scenario to work properly. This post: [No notification data in Write/Notification set-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916457/no-notification-data-in-write-notification-set-up) is almost what I need however, when I use the code posted, I'm unable to capture any data on my peripheral, which in turn doesn't return a response since I'm not sending back a response. When I switch to a long write builder I'm able to write to my peripheral and see the data flow in, but upon returning a response from my peripheral, nothing is captured in my notification subscription.

Here's my code:

```
 private void writeNotify(RxBleDevice peripheral, byte[] payload) {
    Disposable connectionSubscription = peripheral.establishConnection(false)
            .flatMap( // when the connection is available...
                    rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(notifyCharacteristic)), // ... setup the notification...
                    (rxBleConnection, notifyObservable) -> Observable.combineLatest( // ... when the notification is setup...
                            rxBleConnection.createNewLongWriteBuilder().setBytes(payload).setCharacteristicUuid(UUID.fromString(writecharateristic)).setMaxBatchSize(20).build(), // ... write the characteristic...
                            //rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(writecharateristic), payload).toObservable(), // ... write the characteristic...
                            notifyObservable, // ... and observe for the first notification on the AP_SCAN_DATA
                            (writtenBytes, responseBytes) -> responseBytes
                    )
            )
            .flatMap(observable -> observable) // ... flatMap the result as it is Observable<byte[]>...// ... and finish after first response is received to cleanup notifications
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    responseBytes -> {
                        String data = new String(responseBytes);
                    },
                    throwable -> {

                    }
            );
}
```

Separately, I've attempted to handle this as 2 operations where I set up my notification characteristic after performing a long write to my peripheral. Where I subscribe to the observeConnectionStateChanges method on my peripheral and wait for the disconnecting state to fire before setting up my notification characteristic. In this scenario I actually am able to receive partial responses so I know that the notification characteristic is working. I'm just not implementing this correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain what is the intended scenario step by step?